# Define cross-module/global variable from __init__.py

Tags: python, import

I am trying to simplify my package by making importing straightforward (like `requests` module does).

For that, I thought using `__init__.py` would be the best choice. Since, when user imports my package, `__init__.py` is called. Then i add little code inside, which imports object from specific module.

Please imagine, That my package and class object both have same names:

```
# __init__.py
from index import packagename  # This is class object
myclass = myclass  # This is just example to be substituted, I know it has no effect
print(myclass)
```

Whenever package is imported, Python logs the type of myclass:

`<class 'packagename.index.packagename'>  # "packagename" in the beginning is my package, "packagename" in the end is class object`

However, New instance to the class is not set:

`<module 'packagename' from 'packagename/__init__.pyc'>`

---

From my research i couldn't find any significantly reliable answer for my question yet (apologies if i missed something), However, in short, How could i define variable from `__init__.py` so it can be used by user?

So whenever user imports `packagename`, variable `packagename` will be instance of class object and not a module.

Thanks!

Comment: `myclass = myclass` - what were you expecting that to do?

Comment: @user2357112 i expected nothing from it, just added my example of improper (insignificant in this case) definition of variable. I expected importing from `__init__.py` to work though...

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do here. Importing `myclass` into `__init__.py` allows you to do `from package import myclass` rather than `from package.index import myclass`. What else are you hoping to do?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Apologies, i substituted example values incorrectly, I am importing `myclass` from index module `from index import myclass`. 
So let's say package name is the same as name of the class, What i'm trying to do is to import class when package is imported, So for example, when i import `MyPackageName` module `MyPackageName` class object will be imported and substituted.

Comment: Updated the answer with more appropriate details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out.

`requests` package uses the same technique as i did, Their functions are imported from `__init__.py` right away, single example:

`from .api import request, get, head, post, patch, put, delete, options`

However, This functions are imported only inside from package, So they still should be called from package:

`requests.post`

So in my case, Package and Class Object have the same names, But unfortunately, i don't think they can replace each other in a neat way.

If my package was called Apple and Class Object inside `index.py` module was called Apple too.

If i have imported Apple Class Object from `__init__.py`, I would call it like this:

`Apple.Apple` (where Apple[0] is the name of package and Apple[1] is the name of class object)